# How to enable regions (code folding) on non-.pas files?

Tags: delphi, logging, delphi-xe2

Our `.log` files are plain-text files, that sometimes contain a rather large series of request/response dumps.

I'd really like to surround those with an appropriate `{$REGION} / {$ENDREGION}` block, and have them fold away when viewed in a capable IDE like Delphi (omnipresent on our developer machines).

However, Delphi doesn't seem to want to apply the code folding to anything that is not a `.pas`.

Even though I associated `.log` files with Pascal Source formatting, I just get syntax highlighting, no code folding.

Is there any secret trick to make that happen?

Comment: ALas -- I don't believe there is a way to do that, no. I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @NickHodges Perhaps it is not that easy. You can not be sure that `{$REGION}` would still be comment in some PHP or HTML or C or whatever source file you open in the IDE. Then you need to implement formats databases and sometimes auto-detection and you should not interfere with conventiosn of other IDEs (u may be pretty sure that RAD studio would be used for Delphi programs, but for C or HTML choice is vast). So it not that "just does not disable" simplistic,

Comment: It would be nice, for example, if it worked in Include files, anyways.  Don't ask me why I have include files that need code folding. (Argh!)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. As you already said, this only works on .pas files. I have no idea why Embarcadero did not enable this for all files.

But you can create a ticket on Codegear and maybe it will take care of it on the next release.